# How to determine if this geometry is flat

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

How do I determine whether the following geometry is flat?

$$\mathrm{d}s^2=\left(\frac{v}{u}+\frac{1}{uv}\right)\mathrm{d}u^2+\left(\frac{u}{v}+\frac{u}{v^3}\right)\mathrm{d}v^2+2\left(1-\frac{1}{v^2}\right)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$

Thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 2):

Just compute the Riemann tensor. The result is $R^\mu_{\nu\alpha\beta}=0$. This metric is flat.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have used the 2D version of the Riemann tensor given by R(abcd) = K ( g(ac)g(bd) - g(ad)g(cb) ) and all of the terms cancel expect the 1/v^2 terms. So I am left with 4K/v^2 instead of 0. What am I missing? :/

Comment: This formula simply expresses the fact that in 2d Riemann has only one independent component. You still need to compute what the curvature scalar K is.

Comment: How do I calculate K? I cannot seem to figure out why this space is flat when I get a non zero term. Does this mean K must be zero? If so could you please show me how. Thanks

Comment: Are you taking a class in GR or diff geom? $K=R$ where $R=R^\alpha_\alpha$ and $R_{\alpha\beta}=R^{\mu}_{\alpha\mu\beta}$. There is no real shortcut to computing at least one element of Riemann from the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: I just spoke to my lecturer and he said that it can be shown to be flat without using the Riemann curvature tensor. It is G.R. All I somehow need to do is show that the line element can be expressed as ds^2=dx^2 + dy^2. There must be another way. It's only a 2D metric.

Comment: Once you know that the metric is flat it is of course the case that you know that such a transformation must exist. There are some systematic ways of finding them (google Riemann normal coordinates), but you can also just guess.

Comment: I don't think I'd be able to guess how u and v are related to x and y here lol. Can you explain to me how to got the Riemann tensor to be zero? What formula did you use? Did you have to find the geodesic equations and compute the Christoffel symbols?

Comment: The easiest way is to compute Riemann from the Christoffel symbols. These days, you can do that in no time using a Mathematica tensor package (this is what I did).  This is just 2d, so doing it by hand is not that hard. If you want to avoid this, you can compute the geodesics. This will allow you to see that the space is flat (geodesic acceleration is zero), and give you a set of normal coordinates (which in a flat geometry should just map to x,y).

Comment: Ok thanks I will give it a go :) Much appreciated

Comment: I just downloaded a free trial of mathematica and put the metric into a a program and the Riemann tensor came out with all sorts of complex terms and it certainly didn't simplify to zero...

Comment: See above (added math script).

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen the Riemann tensor yet, then I guess the best way would be to guess functions x and y of u and v such that your statement there is true, and equals a flat geometry.

I would also think that, if this is the only method you have access to, then this will be a flat geometry, since it's less possible to guess that there isn't a solution.

First I note that, if there are coordinates x and y related to u and v such that:

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \mathrm{d}x(u,v)^2  +  \mathrm{d}y(u,v)^2$$

then by substituting the following:

$$\mathrm{d}x(u,v) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u }\mathrm{d}u + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v }\mathrm{d}v  \\\ \mathrm{d}y(u,v) =\frac{\partial y }{\partial u }\mathrm{d}u + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v }\mathrm{d}v$$

We get:

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \left[ \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u }\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u }\right)^2\right]\mathrm{d}u^2  +  \left[ \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v }\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial v }\right)^2\right] \mathrm{d}v^2 + 2  \left[\frac{\partial x}{\partial u }\frac{\partial x}{\partial v } + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u } \frac{\partial y}{\partial v }  \right]\mathrm{d}u \ \mathrm{d}v $$

Which gives me some clues to guess with when I compare with your original

$$\mathrm{d}s^2=\left(\frac{v}{u}+\frac{1}{uv}\right)\mathrm{d}u^2+\left(\frac{u}{v}+\frac{u}{v^3}\right)\mathrm{d}v^2+2\left(1-\frac{1}{v^2}\right)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$

Specifically:

$$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u }\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u }\right)^2 = \frac{v}{u}+\frac{1}{uv} $$
$$  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v }\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial v }\right)^2 = \frac{u}{v}+\frac{u}{v^3}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u }\frac{\partial x}{\partial v } + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u } \frac{\partial y}{\partial v }  = 1-\frac{1}{v^2} $$

My first guess was that the derivatives of x corresponded to v/u and u/v, but that was an assumption. It turned out be be correct however, as I found the consistent functions:

$$x = 2\sqrt{u \ v}$$
$$y = 2\sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}$$

for which the derivative equations hold, and hence there do exist coordinates for which the line element is flat, and so the geometry is flat.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the previous answer, I asked him and he said it was wrong.

You want to find a way of expressing the result in the form ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 so find which terms come from squaring an expression of a*du+b*dv where a and b are the coefficients involving u and v.

OLD:

Are you in the UoN fourth year Gravity module? I believe u and v are light cone co-ordinates although I'm not 100% on this - check page 47 of the notes if you're on my course (he's capitalised them for some reason).

Just get them in terms of x and y and evaluate the metric components, then check if they meet the flatness condition in section  8.

Comment: I am indeed. Have you tried this? I just got a complete mess with x and y terms all over the place that cannot be simplified to find the minkowski metric. I've tried going in reverse where I look for an equation for dx and dy so that when is square and add them together it comes out to be the original line element. It almost worked except for a minus sign that I cannot get rid of...